# Integer Division?

Tags: c++, division

Regarding the code shown below:

```
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    const int n = 10000;
    const int K = 10;
    double* matrix = new double[n * n];

    for(int k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        double ai = (double)i/double(n);
        double aj = (double)i/double(n);
                matrix[i * n + j] += pow(n, (double)k / K) / exp((double)k / K) * pow(sin(ai),2) * pow(sin(aj),2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is the way that lines

```
double ai = (double)i/double(n);
double aj = (double)i/double(n);
```

are defined is because we want floating-point division as opposed to integer division?

In addition, why are the operands cast in the way they are, i.e (double)i/double(n) instead of double(i)/double(n)?

Comment: yes, it's the "old" way of csasting (which should be OK for a `double`) . Note that if  `i` was already `double` it would not be necessary to cast => which menas only one of them **must** be casted, but casting both makes it easy to read. Also, I don't know the pourpose of your code, but you could consider `n` to  be `const double`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because if i and n are two integers as follow:

```
int i = ...; 
int n = ...;
double ai = i/n
```

This will be an integer division. Say i=5 and n=9, even ai being a double it will end up with 0 as result.

You can either cast i or n to tell the compiler that you want a float division.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Actually, it would be enough to cast just one of the operands, but some programmers prefer to cast all the operands for consistency and more clarity.

Comment: Why are the operands cast differently? We have (double)i and double(n) - why not have them as double(i) and double(n)?

Comment: Shouldn’t make difference.